# How to save multiple bool from list in Flutter with SharedPreferences

Tags: list, flutter, sharedpreferences

I have created a bool List:

```
List<bool> switchbool = [true, true, true, true];
```

On change of a switch, the value change (pretty obvious...). But I would like to store those information exactly as they are in the list, because I use them like this:

```
Switch(
       value: switchbool[index],
       onChanged: (value) {
       _saveBoolFromSharedPref(value, app[index]);
       setState(() {
    switchbool[index] = value;
    });
 },
)
```

But with this it doesn't load the true or false stored in the sharedPreferences that I saved:

```
Future<void> _getBoolFromSharedPref() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    switchbool.length = app.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < app.length; i += 1) {
        final myBool = prefs.getBool(app[i]) ?? false;
    }
}
```

And here is the `_saveBoolFromSharedPref`:

```
Future<bool> _saveBoolFromSharedPref(bool value, String appName) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool(appName, value);
    //print(switchbool);
}
```

Any advice will be wonderful, thanks a lot!

If I could maybe retrieve the data from the value field on the switch with a future void but I haven't seen anywhere any answer...

Comment: Can you add your _saveBoolFromSharedPref method too please?

Comment: @zeus it should be ok?

Comment: Check my answer @Malopieds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe store your values in a map and then decode/encode them. Like following:

```
var jsn = prefs.getString('Map');
Map = json.decode(jsn);


 var jsn = json.encode(Map);
 prefs.setString('Map', jsn);
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: well first of all thanks for your reply, but i don't understand how should i use a map, I haven't seen a possibility to store bool in it, but i have to convert it to String? Sorry, i'm new to flutter but thanks a lot!

Comment: The de- and encoding provides the possibility to store it in sharedPreferences... Maybe you can do the same with a list, I am not sure

Comment: well i adapt  with [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/flutter-how-to-save-objects-in-sharedpreferences-b7880d0ee2e4) website and evertyhting worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `_getBoolFromSharedPref` method.

```
Future<void> _getBoolFromSharedPref() async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
switchbool.length = app.length;
for (var i = 0; i < app.length; i += 1) {
  switchbool[i] = prefs.getBool(app[i]) ?? false;
}
```

Comment: I already tried it but thanks, it look like the List switchbool is taking first and the _getBoolFromSharedPref isn't even listened :/

Comment: @Malopieds Sorry I don't get what you mean by "is taking first and the _getBoolFromSharedPref isn't even listened"

Comment: yes it's not very clear what i meant was like the List had the pryority over the future void, so it was always stored as "false". But the answer of rottler35 worked like a charm but thanks for your help!